# \newtoks token seems to have local scope

Tags: environments, quoting, grouping, token-lists

I want to collect the first line of a `quotation` to use later. I have used `\newtoks` for a similar purpose so tried it here, this way:

```
\documentclass[12pt] {article} 

\newtoks{\qfirstlineinternal}
\newcommand{\firstline}[1]{%
  \qfirstlineinternal=\expandafter{#1}
 #1
}

\begin{document}

\qfirstlineinternal=\expandafter{\the\qfirstlineinternal initial value}

debug: before quotation -\the\qfirstlineinternal-

\begin{quotation}
debug: in quotation before: -\the\qfirstlineinternal-

\firstline{This is the first line of a quotation,}

debug: in quotation after: -\the\qfirstlineinternal-

which continues on more lines.
\end{quotation}

debug: after quotation: -\the\qfirstlineinternal-
\end{document}
```

Here's the output document, showing that the value of the token set inside the `quotation` environment is lost when that environment ends:

[image]

The `quotation` environment seems to have created a new local instance of my token. How can I prevent that?

Comment: Related Question: [What is the difference between local and global in a TeX meaning?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94710/what-is-the-difference-between-local-and-global-in-a-tex-meaning).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assignments in TeX are by default local to the group in which they are performed. Setting the value of a register is an assignment, as are macro definitions and other assorted actions.

All LaTeX environment (well, almost all, but the exceptions are irrelevant here) form a group, so if one wants that an assignment to a register survives when the group ends, the assignment has to be marked as `\global`.

An assignment to the token register `\qfirstlineinternal` takes the form

```
\qfirstlineinternal={<something>}
```

and in order to make it global it's sufficient to say

```
\global\qfirstlineinternal={<something>}
```

The `\expandafter` that is frequently seen in this context is used to *add* to the contents of the token register:

```
\global\qfirstlineinternal=\expandafter{\the\qfirstlineinternal<something>}
```

will append `<something>` to the previous value of the token register, because the assignment is performed after `\expandafter` has caused the expansion of `\the`, which in turn delivers the contents of `\qfirstlineinternal`. So the `\expandafter` is by no means necessary: its presence depends on what the register is supposed to contain.

The same considerations hold for registers allocated with `\newcount`, `\newdimen` or `\newskip`. Notice that the allocations themselves are global, but this has no influence on value assignments to the registers.

To the contrary, when a LaTeX counter is defined with `\newcounter{foo}`, value assignments to `foo` performed with `\stepcounter{foo}`, `\refstepcounter{foo}`, `\setcounter{foo}{<number>}` or `\addtocounter{foo}{<number>}` are always *global* (it would otherwise be quite difficult to implement assigning the number to a caption, which might be inside a `minipage` nested in a `figure` environment).

Comment: Thanks. I understand `\expandafter` now. I used it in my example because I it was there in code I borrowed to solve a previous problem. It probably wasn't necessary there but I followed the not broken don't fix it model.

Answer (score 7):

Modifications to a token inside a group is specific (or local) to that group (your group being the `quotation` environment). Prepending this assignment with `\global` breaks the barrier:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newtoks{\qfirstlineinternal}
\newcommand{\firstline}[1]{%
  \global\qfirstlineinternal={#1}%
  #1%
}
\begin{document}
%...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the use of `%` to avoid spurious spaces in your output.

Comment: The `\expandafter` seems to be irrelevant (or even wrong).

Comment: @egreg: Seems irrelevant, sure. Wrong, perhaps, depending on the implementation. It's not problematic here, since the stored tokens are text (fully expanded).

Comment: The problem could arise precisely when `#1` starts with a macro.

Comment: I learned from stackoverflow about the `%` to avoid spurious whitespace but haven't developed the proper habit. I will try from now on.