# What is the difference between local and global in a TeX meaning?

Tags: macros, grouping

In [tikz declare function and babel french option](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86023/4918) it came to the question about the difference between local and global in a TeX meaning.

In the linked question the babel shorthand `;` should be deactivated inside a `{tikzpicture}`, which can be done with

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \shorthandoff{;}
   ...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Similar question, similar answer (from @egreg): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47570/newtoks-token-seems-to-have-local-scope

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The concept of *global* and *local* has to do with assigning meaning to a token or a value to a register.

## Tokens and their meaning

Tokens are the basic food of TeX and they come in two varieties: *character tokens* and *symbolic tokens*. Roughly speaking, the latter are those that we represent as "backslash+characters".

The meaning of a character token depends on the combination of "character code" and "category code" of that character; for instance, under the normal settings, the character `A` corresponds to the pair (65,11), while `{` to the pair (123,1). It's category code 1 that gives `{` its special meaning as group and argument delimiter. Similarly, `\` corresponds to (92,0), so that the backslash acts as marker for symbolic tokens.

Many tokens have a *predefined* meaning when TeX starts a job. Every character token has a character code (that can't be changed) and a category code (which can be changed later); some symbolic tokens are *primitive*, so that TeX doesn't start from nothing.

### Assignments

At any moment, new symbolic tokens can be assigned a meaning or the meaning of already known tokens can be changed (for character tokens only the category code). What TeX does with a token depends on the context. For instance, `\tracingmacros` is a (primitive) integer register; with

```
\tracingmacros=1
```

TeX will *assign* the value 1 to the integer register, while with

```
\count255=\tracingmacros
```

the current value stored in `\tracingmacros` will be assigned as the value stored in the integer register `\count255`.

Both are examples of *assignments*. Every time the meaning of a token or a value stored in a register or array is modified, we are doing an assignment. Listing all kinds of assignments would be too long. The basic types are, in addition to those shown before,

```
\def\cs<parameter text>{<replacement text>}
\let\cs=<token>
\catcode<8 bit number>=<4 bit number>
<font selector>
```

(when LuaTeX or XeTeX are used, the `<8 bit number>` is `<21 bit number>`). In the last type `<font selector>` denotes a symbolic token that selects a font as the current one (such an assignment is performed behind the scenes by LaTeX when one uses `\bfseries` or `\textit`). There are many more, but this would take us too far.

To be precise, assignments cannot be performed at really *any* time. TeX doesn't perform assignments only when executing commands (not when it is expanding macros); in particular it will not perform assignments when computing the replacement text in an `\edef` or when writing out the result of a `\write` operation.

### Active characters

A particular type of character token is one whose category code is 13. When TeX finds such a character it looks for its meaning as if it were a symbolic token and that meaning has to be assigned with `\def` (or variations thereof) or `\let`. This is the well known case of `~`.

### Groups

By rule *every* assignment (well, almost every, see the “Exceptions” section) is scoped and it loses its force when the *current group* ends. What's a group? TeX can open a group in several ways:

1. With a `{` that hasn't the role of argument delimiter; the group will end with the `}` at the same brace level. One can use `\bgroup` for `{` or `\egroup`  for `}` with the same effect (*simple group*).
2. With `\begingroup`; the current group will end with the corresponding `\endgroup` (*semisimple group*).
3. When the text to be typeset in a `\vbox`, `\vtop`, `\vcenter` or `\hbox` is being absorbed (*box group*).
4. When the text for an alignment cell is being absorbed; it is almost the same as a box group (*alignment group*).
5. When `$` or `$$` start a math formula (*math formula group*).
   <sub>The tokens `$$` that start or end a math display are automatically supplied by LaTeX; never use `$$...$$` directly in LaTeX</sub>
6. Other special cases that can be found in the TeXbook or in TeX by Topic (for instance, `\left` starts a group, ended by the matching `\right`).

Thus `\begingroup\tensl ABC \endgroup DEF` will print "*ABC* DEF" because the assignment of the current font ends its force at `\endgroup`. Conversely

```
\def\my#1{-- #1 --}
\my{\tensl ABC} DEF
```

will print "-- *ABC* -- *DEF*" and continue to use slanted type, because the `\tensl` declaration has not been seen inside a group.

### Global assignments

Each assignment can be prefixed by `\global` and, in this case, its effect will transcend the current group. An abbreviation for `\global\def` is `\gdef`; so

```
\begingroup
\catcode`-=\active % \active here means 13
\gdef-{not a hyphen}
\endgroup
```

shows both kinds of assignments at the same time. The category code of `-` is changed only locally, but the meaning of `-` as active character is assigned globally. Whenever TeX will find a (45,13) pair, the definition of `-` as active character will be used, but `-` won't be active by default after `\endgroup`. More on this later.

### LaTeX

What's to be considered as a group in LaTeX? In addition to the general TeX constructs above, also environments form groups, because of how LaTeX implements `\begin` and `\end`, issuing `\begingroup` with the former and `\endgroup` with the latter. With a notable exception, that of the `document` environment which is however important only from a theoretical point of view, since there can be only one `document` environment. But also the arguments to `\mbox`, `\makebox`, `\fbox`, `\framebox`, `\sbox`, `\savebox` and `\parbox` will be absorbed as groups, because they internally use `\hbox`, `\vbox`, `\vtop` or `\vcenter`. Similarly, every cell in a `tabular` or `tabbing` environment will make a group by itself, being a special case of an alignment group.

The LaTeX commands `\newcommand`, `\renewcommand`, `\newenvironment` and `\renewenvironment` are wrappers for `\def`, so they act only *locally*, but can't be preceded by `\global`. So there's basically no way to do global assignments in LaTeX except by using lower level commands. An exception are assignments to LaTeX *counters* which are always global (see at the bottom).

### The problem with the French semicolon

In order to cope with the peculiarities of French typography, `babel` changes some characters to category code 13 (active). This can cause problems with TikZ that uses the semicolon as its statement delimiter, but also the colon in its syntax. The developers of TikZ have tried their best in avoiding problems with this setting, but sometimes things can go wrong. What does

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}
```

do precisely? The details are quite involved, but among other things the following will basically be performed (however, this is a very broad simplification):

```
\begingroup
\catcode`;=\active % \active here means 13
\gdef;{\unskip\penalty10000 \thinspace\string;}
\catcode`:=\active % \active here means 13
\gdef:{\unskip~\string:}
\endgroup
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`;=\active \catcode`:=\active}
```

So when `;` or `:` are found in the document, they will be active and expand like a macro to the replacement text above. This of course is *not* what TikZ expects from the statement delimiter, for instance.

An example is in [tikz declare function and babel french option](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86023/tikz-declare-function-and-babel-french-option)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{declare function={Carre(\t)=\t*\t;}}
  \draw plot [domain=-1:1] (\x,{Carre(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The semicolon delimiting the `\draw` statement is correctly interpreted, because TikZ knows how to deal with an active semicolon in that situation. But the statement delimiter in `\tikzset` is seen as such only too late.

In order to solve the issue there are two methods:

1. Put the `\tikzset` declaration in the preamble, where the semicolon is *not* active.
2. Use a local assignment to make the semicolon inactive in the `tikzpicture` environment

Thus both

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{declare function={Carre(\t)=\t*\t;}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw plot [domain=-1:1] (\x,{Carre(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \shorthandoff{;}
  \tikzset{declare function={Carre(\t)=\t*\t;}}
  \draw plot [domain=-1:1] (\x,{Carre(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

will work; `\shorthandoff{;}` is Babel's way of turning off (locally) the active nature of a character token and basically means

```
\catcode`;=<whatever category code ; had at the start of the job>
```

without forcing us to know that the code to use is 12. Since the assignment is local, it will end at `\end{tikzpicture}`, so after that the character `;` will be again active.

**With TikZ version 3.00, the `babel` library has been introduced, so the problems discussed above may be irrelevant when**

```
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
```

**is used.** (Added 2015-01-02.)

### Other uses of local assignments

Suppose one wants to have "named theorems" in addition to "generic" ones. For instance in the book one's writing it is planned to have

> **Rank-nullity theorem 1.4
>
> Gram-Schmidt theorem 2.3**

among other statements labeled plainly **Theorem**. One strategy can be to define a new theorem-like environment for each name, sharing the counter with the plain `theorem` environment. One can do better, though:

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{namedtheoremaux}[theorem]{\protect\thistheoremname}

\newcommand{\thistheoremname}{}
\newenvironment{namedtheorem}[1]
  {\renewcommand{\thistheoremname}{#1}\begin{namedtheoremaux}}
  {\end{namedtheoremaux}}
```

so that the input can be

```
\begin{namedtheorem}{Rank-nullity theorem}
...
\end{namedtheorem}

...

\begin{namedtheorem}{Gram-Schmidt theorem}
...
\end{namedtheorem}
```

The `\protect` in the definition is not necessary with the standard `\newtheorem` of LaTeX or the one provided by `amsthm`; it is for `ntheorem` and does no harm otherwise.

The redefinition of `\thistheoremname` is local, so it will affect only the current `namedtheorem` environment.

### Exceptions

Some assignments made by TeX are *inherently global*. The most frequently used assignments of this kind are

```
\hyphenchar\font=`-
\hyphenchar\font=-1
```

The first one tells TeX that the character to use as a hyphen when typesetting in the current font should be the normal hyphen; the second one tells that hyphenation with this font is suppressed.

It's not a good idea to say

```
This is a normal paragraph and the following word must not be
{\hyphenchar\font=-1 hyphenated} but others can
```

because *no* word in the paragraph and in the following ones using the same font will be hyphenated, since the assignment is global even if not preceded by `\global`; however

```
This is a normal paragraph and the following word must not be
\hyphenchar\font=-1 hyphenated \hyphenchar\font=`- but others can
```

won't do the trick either, because TeX uses only one hyphenchar for a font, the one that's associated to it when the paragraph ends.

### LaTeX again

LaTeX operations on counters

- `\setcounter`
- `\addtocounter`
- `\stepcounter` and `\refstepcounter`

are realized as *global* assignments. To the contrary, `\setlength` operates locally (and preceding it by `\global` doesn't work).

Comment: This is a great answer!

Answer (score 12):

The answer by Tobi is not precise.

By `\shorthandsoff{;}` you do not really *redefine* `;`, you change catcode of `;` from `active` to `other` so that inside `tikzpicture` it is not executed at all.

This means that inside `tikzpicture` it will work correctly, but inside `\textbf{...}` (or any other command that takes arguments) it will not. This is due to characters being read with the catcode they have at the time of reading, not at the time of execution. The macro assignments (`\def`, `\newcommand`, `\let`, ...) are, on the other hand, done at the time of execution, and will therefore work even in macro argument.

---

Notice that a command that does not enclose its parameter in group (either `\begingroup...\endgroup`, `{...}` or `\bgroup...\egroup`) will not make the assignment "local inside the argument", but "local in the scope of the macro". See the following examples:

```
\newcommand\mparen[1]{(#1)}
\def\A{a}

\textbf{\A\ \def\A{b}\A}\ \A % result: a b a

\mparen{\A\ \def\A{b}\A}\ \A % result: a b b
```

For this reason, it might be better do add the grouping in the definition of `\mparen`:

```
\newcommand\mparen[1]{({#1})}
```

---

A last comment to show how catcode assignments differ from macro assignments. The command `\makeatletter` assigns `@` a catcode `letter`, so that it can be used in macro names. The command `\makeatother` reverts this. So try the following example:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mparen[1]{(#1)}
\def\A{a}
\def\A@B{b}
\makeatother

\begin{bfseries}
\makeatletter
\A\ \A@B % result: a b
\end{bfseries}

\A\ \A@B % result: a a@B

\textbf{\makeatletter \A\ \A@B}% result: a a@B

\A\ \A@B % result: a a@B

\mparen{\makeatletter \A\ \A@B}% result: a a@B

\A\ \A@B % result: a b
```

---

I was asked to provide explanation as what happens in the last three lines. I'll try to explain it step by step. By `r:` I mark what TeX **R** eads. By `o:`  I mark what is **O** utput and processed. By `m:` I mark the meaning of the macros

```
r: \A 
m: \A -> a
  r: a % we now read the definition of \A
  o: letter `a`
r: \ 
o: space
r: \A % remember, @ is not a letter
m: \A -> a
  r: a
  o: letter `a`
r: @
o: symbol `@`
r: B
o: letter `B`
r: empty line
o: end of paragraph

r: \mparen
m: \mparen#1 -> (#1)
r: {\makeatletter \A\ \A@B} % at this moment, TeX core reads 
     % the arguments. Since @ is still not a letter, sequence \A@B
     % comprises three tokens, `\A`  `@`  `B`
  r: (
  o: symbol `(`
  r: #1
    r: \makeatletter
    o: change of catcode of `@` % notice we ARE NOT IN A GROUP
    r: \A
    m: \A -> a
      r: a
      o: letter `a`
    r: \ 
    o: space
    r: \A
    m: \A -> a
      r: a
      o: letter `a`
    r: @ % catcode is now "letter", but it was actually read
         % couple steps before where catcode was "other"
    o: symbol `@`
    r: B
    o: letter `B`
  r: )
  o: symbol `)`
r: empty line
o: end of paragraph

r: \A
m: \A -> a
  r: a
  o: letter `a`
r: \ 
o: space
r: \A@B % catcode of @ is "letter" now so it's treatened as a part
     % of macro name
m: \A@B -> b
  r: b
  o: letter `b`
```

Comment: Thanks for this addition! Is there anything wrong in my anser that should be deleted/corrected?

Comment: @Tobi I'm not sure, I'm just afraid that you somehow mix issues of catcodes with issues of macro definitions. However, they are not the same and it might lead to confusion.

Comment: I guess I’m aware of the difference of catcodes and definitions but they both are scoped in a group aren’t they?

Comment: @Tobi Yes, they are. But they behave differently. I should add an example on this into this asnwer.

Comment: I changed my answer a little and referred in it to yours …

Comment: I like your last example.  But, I'm also baffled.  Everything works as I would expect it to, except the last two examples.  There's something I feel is very counter-intuitive going on in those two.  Could you elaborate a bit about what's going on with them and why the `\makeatletter` appears to be too late in taking effect?

Comment: @A.Ellett better?

Comment: Thank you for your further details.  I still finding it counter-intuitive.  So the only way to get `\makeatletter` behave as a naive individual like myself would believe, is to write something like `\expandafter\mparen\begingroup\makeatletter \A\ \A@B\endgroup%`.  TeX's digestive tract continues to show me that I must think things through more carefully.

Comment: @A.Ellett no, that would not help of course. You can try it. I think the result will be `()a b` instead of the wished `(a b)`

Comment: Argh.  You are so right.  I did try and I thought I was being successful in my work around.  Well, I'll just have think about this.  Nevertheless, I greatly appreciate you taking the time to write out step by step TeX's approach to those last three lines.

Answer (score 8):

In TeX, every assignment (definition, counter change, catcode change, etc.) is local, i.e., it is scoped inside a so-called "group", except when it’s made global explicitly. A group is everything between two braces, i.e.,

```
outside {inside} outside
```

(except when the braces delimit an argument), everything inside an environment, i.e.,

```
outside
\begin{env}
   inside
\end{env}
outside
```

or everything between `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`,

```
outside
\begingroup
   inside
\endgroup
outside
```

The latter are used inside the definitions of `\begin#1` and `\end#1`.

An example may illustrate that:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\A}{A}

\begin{document}
\A\ expands to A

\begin{center}
    \A\ expands to A \\
    \renewcommand{\A}{AA}
    \A\ expands to AA
    
    \newcommand{\B}{B}
    \B\ expands to B
\end{center}

\A\ expands to A and not AA!

\B\ is undefined outside the group here
\end{document}
```

The practical use of this is to keep changes of definitions local or, e.g., to set the font for some words like in `normal {\tiny tiny} normal`.

The problem with

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \shorthandoff{;}
   ...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

is that one must add the `\shorthandoff` in every `{tikzpicture}` since it’s deactivation (i.e. catcode change, see [tohecz answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94715/4918)) keeps local inside the current `{tikzpicture}`. Sure, it is possible to add the `\shorthandoff` to the preamble but then it is swichted of for normal text too. It is possible to add the deactivation macro to the definition of `\begin{tikzpicture}` with `etoolbox`’ `\AtBeginEnvironment`

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\shorthandoff{;}}
```

or in this case with TikZ styles, like Jake said:

```
\tikzset{
    every picture/.prefix style={
        execute at begin picture=\shorthandoff{;}
    }
}
```