# Why is \setlength ineffective inside a tabular environment?

Tags: tables, spacing, lengths

Why is `\setlength` ineffective inside a `tabular` environment? Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength{\globallength}
\newlength{\locallength}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\globallength}{10pt}%
\begin{tabular}{l}
\setlength{\locallength}{10pt}%

\hspace*{10pt}. \\

\hspace*{\globallength}. \\

\hspace*{\locallength}. \\

\hspace*{0pt}. \\

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

While the first two dots are well-aligned, the third one is different and behaves as if `\locallength` were `0pt`. Why is that, and what can I do? I want to use `\setwidth` inside the `tabular` environment, so setting the length outside of the environment is not really an option.

Comment: Your length registers are `locally` set, i.e. in a group. A table cell **is** a group! That's why you need a `\global\setlength{....}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: please post answer.  Or is this question a duplicate?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `\global\setlength` will not work with package `calc`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Thanks, I did not know this. But `calc` is no issue here, as far as I can see

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The other version `\setlength{\global\locallength}` will work with `calc`, but it won't for `\addtolength`. A way independent from the implementation of `\setlength`: `\setlength{\locallength}{...}\global\locallength=\locallength`.

Comment: Prefixing `\setlength`, `\settowidth`, `\settoheight` or `\settodepth` with `\global` has never been supported.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know a table **cell** is its own group; I was aware that a `tabular` environment is one, but I had not suspected it even for a table *line*.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a table line here, surely if a table row is a row of cells, each of which is a group then a one-cell row, as here is naturally a group?

Comment: The question simply asked "why", in that sense I thought that @ChristianHupfer had answered it. :-)

Comment: Yes, I mean a *row*, not a *line*. My comment was about my understanding of groups in a table *before* asking this question, when I would have guessed that even a table row is not a group. I know better now.

Comment: there is no group that  corresponds to a table row, only the groups that correspond to each cell.

Comment: The burden of a non-native speaker... I'll try again: Before asking this question, I was sure the smallest entity in a table that would form a group is the table itself, not a row (this is what my last two comments are about), and certainly not a cell. I know now that a cell is a group, which does not mean that a row is a group, but which means that there are groups "at *or below* the level of a single table row".

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: Thanks, but there are answers now and my comments were opposed already (about a feature not in the OP althought ;-)) and an answer by me would be most likely disregarded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alignment cells are processed inside an implicit group, so local assignments to variables are undone when the group ends.

The kernel definition of `\setlength` is

```
% latex.ltx, line 2181:
\def\setlength#1#2{#1 #2\relax}
```

which is why `\global\setlength` *seems* to work. On the other hand, the definition of `\settowidth` is

```
% latex.ltx, line 2187:
\def\settowidth {\@settodim\wd}
```

and the definition of `\@settodim` is

```
% latex.ltx, line 2183:
\def\@settodim#1#2#3{\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{#3}}#2#1\@tempboxa
       \setbox\@tempboxa\box\voidb@x}
```

Thus `\global\settowidth{\locallength}{abc}` would become

```
\global\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{abc}}\locallength\wd\@tempboxa\setbox\@tempboxa\box\voidb@x
```

which of course is ineffective in making a global assignment to `\locallength`.

Yes, `\settowidth{\global\locallength}{abc}` would work, but it's just by chance.

There is no support in LaTeX for global dimension/skip assignments and you should rely on lower level commands. So a safer way is to define new commands:

```
\makeatletter
\newlength\local@length@for@global
\newcommand\gsetlength[2]{%
  \setlength{\local@length@for@global}{#2}%
  \global#1\local@length@for@global
}
\newcommand{\gsettowidth}[2]{%
  \settowidth{\local@length@for@global}{#2}%
  \global#1\local@length@for@global
}
\makeatother
```

and similarly for `\gsettoheight` and `\gsettodepth` if needed.

This will work even if `calc` is loaded and does not exploit any particular implementation of the “local” commands.

Answer (score 0):

Both `\global\setlength{\locallength}{10pt}` and `\setlength{\global\locallength}{10pt}` seem to work, but I have no idea why that would be required.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210598/30810 made me try it, and @ChristianHupfer's comment explains, why.

In my longer document, `\global\settowidth{...}` did not work; `\settowidth{\global...}` did.