# font families side by side

Tags: fonts, fontspec

for sure nothing that not has been answered already but i can't find it.

How to get roman and sansserif fonts in one document?

I need the LATEX Roman while my document is sans serif.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont{Times-Roman}
\setmonofont{FiraMono-Regular.otf}
\setmainfont{FiraSans}[
    Ligatures=TeX,
    Path = /Users/novski/Library/Fonts/,
    BoldFont = *-Regular,
    BoldItalicFont = *-Italic,
    ItalicFont = *-Italic,
    UprightFont = *-UltraLight,
]
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
 \begin{center}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt} \\ [4mm]
    \Large{\textsc{this Document is Typset with}} \\ [3mm]
    \textrm{ \Huge{\LaTeX{}} }\\ [1mm]
    \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\\
    \vspace*{\fill}
 \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: sansserif Latex instead of roman]

Comment: I should have mentioned that i have a full document that i like to be set in sans serif. This is the last page of that document...

Comment: `{\setmainfont{Times-Roman}\LaTeX}`?

Comment: This works. Can you explain why the font set by '\setromanfont{Times-Roman}' can not be called? To set the main font seams to me as a workaround but not a solution. I wold expect to call the special font and leave the main font for the document untouched...

Comment: Because `\setromanfont` is the outdated equivalent of `\setmainfont` and you override your roman font by making Fira Sans the main font. Alternatively you can do `\newfontfamily\myfont{Times-Roman}` in the preamble and do `{\myfont\LaTeX}`.

Comment: doesn't that mean that i can not exchange this part of text because its depending on a self declared fontname 'myfont' that somebody else needs to declare first? Is it possible to make that exchangeable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit late to the party, but if you just want to make sure the `\LaTeX` command expands correctly without kerning adjustments (*which you can do with the* [`metafont`](https://ctan.org/pkg/metalogo) *package*), you can force the command to use the `Computer Modern` font family.

To achieve this, you redefine the command from where you want to apply it:

```
\let\myLaTeX\LaTeX
\def\LaTeX{\fontfamily{cmr}\rmfamily\selectfont\myLaTeX}
```

You can as easily revert this back to normal by doing:

```
\let\LaTeX\myLaTeX
```

after the `\LaTeX` you need to typeset occurs.

so the following:

```
    % .... %
    \vspace*{2mm}
    \let\myLaTeX\LaTeX % <- Copy \LaTeX here
    \def\LaTeX{\fontfamily{cmr}\rmfamily\selectfont\myLaTeX} % <- Redefine here
    {\Large\mdseries\textsc{The logo with Computer Modern:}\par}
    {\Huge\LaTeX\par}
    \let\LaTeX\myLaTeX % <- Revert changes
    {\Large\mdseries\textsc{The logo with default font:}\par}
    {\Huge\LaTeX\par}
    \vspace*{2mm}
    % .... %
```

Will produce something like this:

[image: result of suggestion above]

---

#### Explanation

1. The `\let\myLaTeX\LaTeX` command will copy `\LaTeX` into `\myLaTeX`, we do this to avoid overwriting the command `\LaTeX` in the next step. *Think of it as "\let \this be the same as \that"*
2. `\def\LaTeX{...}` redefines the `\LaTeX` command sequence with whatever is entered inside the brackets `{...}` (*know as a group*).
3. `{\fontfamily{cmr}\rmfamily\selectfont\myLaTeX}` sets the font `cmr` on what follows, in our case, the previously `\let` (*or copied*) command sequence `\myLaTeX`. Note: I've specifically set `\rmfamily` here to avoid warnings of undefined shapes in some fonts.

This can also be done with *some* of `\TeX` and friends in the same way.

---

#### For the entire document

If you want to use this for every macro, you can put the definition in the preamble of your main *.tex file, as in the MWE below:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[light, default]{sourcesanspro} % <- Using this sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\let\myLaTeX\LaTeX
\def\LaTeX{\fontfamily{cmr}\rmfamily\selectfont\myLaTeX}
\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\par
        \vspace*{2mm}
        {\Large\mdseries\textsc{This Document is typeset with}\par}
        {\Huge\LaTeX\par}
        \vspace*{2mm}
        \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\par
        \vspace*{\fill}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

I generally recommend doing this over making inline changes to fonts. And since LaTeX traditionally is typeset with roman font, I think it should be eaten as intended. Even so, I've added a few options further down.

---

#### Result

To illustrate how this works, I use the `Source Sans Pro` font family as the document font (*like I did in the example above*). This font does not expand `\LaTeX` well (*in my opinion*), as shown below:

[image: image illustrating the use of only Source Sans Pro as default font family]

And here is how it will look once you force the font for `\LaTeX`:

[image: The much better representation]

---

#### Other options

If you want to use the same font type for consistency, you can use a font that \LaTeX expands well with:

For Typewriter fonts, try `pcr` (Courier), which looks like this:

[image: logo typeset with courier]

For Sans Serif fonts, try `phv` (Helvet), which looks like this:

[image: logo typeset with Helvetica]

For Serif fonts, you can also try `ppl` (Palatino), which looks like this:

[image: logo typeset with Palatino]

#### Further reading

1. [How to typeset every TeX related logo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11097/131542)
2. [The difference between local and global scope](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94733/131542)
3. Changing the font of specific words or paragraphs ([LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25251/131542)), ([XeLaTeX & LuaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37251/131542))

Comment: Please note that you are `\def`-overwriting a robust command.

Comment: I have made an update to the answer. Thank you for the insight!

Answer (score 5):

Okay, so let's start with a few problems in your code:

- You set `\setromanfont` and `\setmainfont` where the former is an outdated synonym for the latter. So basically Fira Sans overwrites Times Roman.
- You use size commands like `\Huge` as if they were commands with arguments. Either use them properly in groups (`{\Huge Test}`) or use `\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textHuge}{\Huge}` and then `\textHuge{Text}`.
- Should you ever have more than one line in one of these lines with changed font size consider adding a paragraph break, so that the inter-line-spacing adjusts.

Regarding your problem: You decided to typeset your document in sans serif font. That's fine, but as you use it as main font you might want to disregard the command names and simply use your roman font family as "sans font" as you swapped meanings either way.

Then you are able to use `\textsf` or `\sffamily` on your example and it will work. Btw: `\LaTeX` might not look good in fonts other than Computer/Latin Modern because of kerning issues, so if you really want to emphasize the "Typeset with LaTeX" aspect you might want to adjust the kerning to your font.

For illustration purposes, I have used the Fira fonts included in TeX Live (removed your paths) and Libertinus Serif which is also part of TeX Live.

[image: typeset with LaTeX]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Fira Sans}
\setsansfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setmonofont{Fira Mono}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
 \begin{center}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\par
    \vspace*{2mm}
    {\Large\textsc{This Document is typeset with}\par}
    {\Huge\sffamily\LaTeX\par}
    \vspace*{2mm}
    \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\par
    \vspace*{\fill}
 \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

One thing you could do is to load your serif font as a named font family, say `\libertine`, which most font packages support, then set your sans serif font as your main font (In many packages, this is the `[sfdefault]` package option).

You can then declare the new commands

```
\newcommand\seriffamily{\libertine}
\DeclareTextFontCommand\textserif{\seriffamily}
```

Thus allows you to write `\seriffamily` in place of `\rmfamily` and `\textserif{...}` in place of `\textrm{...}`.

Comment: +1, unfortunately the OP does not like the solution (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451572/font-families-side-by-side/451653#comment1135472_451572)).

Comment: @TeXnician I think the objection is that it makes it hard to change the font, because it depends on a family name. But that's what `\seriffamily` and `\textserif` let you do! Besides, you can always declare the family yourself with `\newfontfamily` or use a documented package interface.

Comment: I think the objection was that it is not possible to simply copy the code to another document irrespective of possible settings in the preamble. But as I said, I second your solution (that's why I wrote +1) and leave it to the OP what he wants to do.

Comment: @TeXnician If the OP wants that, the right approach might be to stick a bunch of `\sffamily` and `\rmfamily` commands all over the place.

Comment: That's what I suggested in my answer ;)

Comment: @TeXnician Must've scrolled past it, sorry. Good answer!