# Display first (sub) environment in an environment

Tags: environments, conditionals

I would like to make a bank of problems of similar type--however, I only want to display the first of each time. For example:

```
\begin{bank}  
\begin{exercise} 2+2
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise} 4+3
\end{exercise}
\end{bank}
```

Would only show the exercise 2+2. Any help on this would be great.

Note: this questions seems similar to [Getting the first line of an environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98079/getting-the-first-line-of-an-environment)

and I've tried something like:

```
\def\getline#1\par{%
\gdef\theline{#1}#1%
}

\newenvironment{bank}{%
  \getline%
}{\theline}
```

but this displays the contents of bank, and then the first environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following MWE uses [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ) to define the `exercise` environment and then condition on whether or not to set its contents (`\BODY`). The condition is set to true at the start of `bank`, and set to false after setting the first `\BODY`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}% http://ctan.org/pkg/environ
\newif\iffirstexercise% Condition for first exercise
\newenvironment{bank}
  {\firstexercisetrue}% Allow first exercise environment to be set
  {}
\NewEnviron{exercise}{%
  \iffirstexercise
    \BODY% Set body of exercise environment
  \fi%
  \global\firstexercisefalse% No more exercise environments are set
}
\begin{document}

\begin{bank}
\begin{exercise} $2+2$
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise} $4+3$
\end{exercise}
\end{bank}

\begin{bank}
\begin{exercise} $7-6$
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise} $4-3$
\end{exercise}
\end{bank}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your `exercise` is unspecified, the code is changed a little.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exercise}
\begin{document}

\long\def\bbank#1  STOP #2\ebank{#1}

%\begin{bank}  
\bbank
%\begin{exercise}
\[
 2+2
\]
%\end{exercise}
% No new paragraph
STOP

%\begin{exercise} 
\[
4+3
\]
%\end{exercise}
%\end{bank}


\[
4+3
\]

\ebank

\end{document}
```

All the work is made by `\long\def\bbank#1  STOP #2\ebank{#1}`. The defintion is long, because your text may be longer than a paragraph. `STOP` is a string that never appears in your code. Please observe, that in this defintion `STOP` doesn't begin a new paragraph, what is commented in an example of usage.